# Can I write "Kindly let me know openly", finishing a letter?

Tags: formality, email, letter-writing

What I want to do is to ask politely for feedback - including feedback that might be left out because it has negative aspects.
So I want to ask the addressee not to ignore or suppress problems because  of political correctness or politeness concerns.

In the closing of an email, I tried to express that with

> Kindly let me know openly

I hope it will get the point across, but perhaps there is a more elegant wording?

The email was in a semiformal situation, but variants depending on level of formality would be good to know.

Example usage:

> Dear Foo!
>
> The Bar thing I messed up, I
>   figured I'll better make it a Baz.
>
> Am I missing something?
>
> Kindly let me know openly.
>   Best regards,
>   Volker

Comment: No, “Kindly let me know openly” does not work. It doesn’t make much sense at first blush, but if you really force it to make sense, it would mean that you’re asking your colleague/friend to reply to you in public, not secretly. I can think of several rather informal ways of saying what you’re looking for (“Just give it to me straight”, “Don’t hold back”, “Let me have it”), but not really any that are even semiformal. I’d probably go for something like, “Please let me know, and be as straightforward as you like—you don’t have to hold back”.

Answer (score 4):

I understand what you wish to say by "openly".  Here're some options:

- Kindly (or Please) be frank and let me know.
- Please feel free to share your thoughts (with me).
- I'd appreciate your outspokenness on this matter.
- Thanks for being straight with me. Be as straight as you'd like.

Comment: +1 for "please be frank". "Be as straight as you can be", on the other hand might imply that the recipient is incapable of being honest (as well as being informal).

Comment: Thanks. I thought that's what it meant - urging the other to open up, without any hesitation. Varying levels of formality was also part of the request, wasn't it?

Comment: "Be straight with me" would be fine. "Be as straight as you can be" *could* be taken to imply 'but I know that's not much, because you're basically crooked', which I'm fairly sure was not intended.

Comment: "Outspokenness" is not quite right.  One wants the addressee to speak _up_, but not speak _out_ (that would be too "open".  Unfortunately, we don't have the form "upspokenness"  (well, except for one attempt in _Time Magazine_ in 1931 http://www.wordola.com/wusage/upspokenness/all.html  but apparently it didn't catch on.)

Comment: "Speak frankly", "speak your mind" are also part of the definitions of "speak out (or up) besides "speak openly" as per Oxford (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/speak-out-or-up?q=speak+out).

Answer (score 2):

> [**Constructive Criticism**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/constructive+criticism): criticism or advice that is useful and intended to help or improve something, often with an offer of possible solutions

*I would appreciate any constructive criticism.*

Answer (score 1):

*Forthright*:

> Please be forthright in your response.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> blah blah

Answer (score 0):

"Openly" is definitely not right. I would go for "Am I missing something? Please be honest [or perhaps *frank*]."

Answer (score -1):

Please let us know if there is anything we need to do our end.

Better English, in my view, would be 'We are happy to accept your proposal. Please let us know if you'd if there is anything you'd like us to do'.